# Why is this question prompting me for a username and password?

Tags: support, images

Today I came across something very odd. When browsing through the site I saw a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213486/vmware-esxi-panic-failed-to-find-hd-boot-partition) which prompted me for a username and password.

[image]

Why am I seeing this? Is it a bug? Please take a look yourself. It happens with every browser whether you're logged in or not.

Comment: That's certainly not a bug; that's due to the asker having embedded two images from this "wg1337.de" website, which apparently requires HTTP auth in order to access the images.

Comment: @maxton it even appears for one picture

Comment: It's probably harmless, but on first sight, this looked like phishing to me.  The German message means "Your Facebook is not here; instead, it is reachable via social.wg1337.de."

Answer (score 52, accepted):

There were two old image links in that question. Whatever they originally linked to is lost to time; now they're broken, and the server they were hosted on is asking for credentials.

I've removed the image links.

Comment: It would it be great if StackExchange cached the media in submissions for posterity and to prevent issues like this.

Comment: @EricKigathi It's already done, when people upload images using the dialog box (drag and drop, copy and paste image or copy and paste link) the images are uploaded to stack.imgur.com and served from there.

Comment: It might be an idea to copy all linked images to imgur, even when they are not uploaded using the dialog box.

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd: Doing that causes legal problems around copyright.

Comment: If SE wanted to prevent this without caching images, they could add the `crossorigin="anonymous"` attribute to the image, as described in my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33586139/prevent-http-basic-authentication-from-displaying-prompt-for-images)  to suppress any auth dialogs.